# I need help toggling text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have a website that I am working on that has 3 `h1` tags that I can click on to call a function, now when I click on it I want to set the innerHTML to something.

I am using HTML and jQuery for this and I have tried:

`uitzendText.innerHTML = $('p#uitzendBureau').text();` But without success.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <h1 class="mt-3" onclick="showText('uitzendBureau');">Uitzend<b class="text-orange">bureau</b></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <h1 class="mt-3" onclick="showText('ymeKamminga');">Yme <b class="text-orange">Kamminga</b></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <h1 class="mt-3" onclick="showText('koeriersDienst');">Koeriers<b class="text-orange">dienst</b></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <p class="text-center" id="uitzendBureau">uitzend</p>
    <p class="text-center" id="ymeKamminga">yme</p>
    <p class="text-center" id="koeriersDienst">koerier</p>
</div>
```

And this is the Javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('uitzendBureau').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('koeriersDienst').innerHTML = '';

function showText(text) {
    let uitzendText = document.getElementById('uitzendBureau');
    let koeriersText = document.getElementById('koeriersDienst');
    let ymeText = document.getElementById('ymeKamminga');

    if (text === 'ymeKamminga') {
        console.log(text);
        ymeText.innerHTML = $('p#ymeKamminga').text();
    }
    if (text === 'uitzendBureau') {
        console.log(text);
        uitzendText.innerHTML = $('p#uitzendBureau').text();
        koeriersText.innerHTML = '';
        ymeText.innerHTML = '';
    }

}
```

The first two lines in the Javascript code are there because I want the visitor to only see the `ymeText` when the page first loads.

Now, I expect the text to change based on the tag they clicked, but this isn't happening.

I don't get any errors in the Console and the `console.log(text);` does give the expected result inside the if statements so it does come in the if.

Comment: Can you add more details about expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question currectly but you want the text in the onclick to appear in the p# element? I made an example for what I think what you mean (will add explanation if this indeed the case)

```js
// reset the html of the elements
$('#uitzendBureau').html('');
$('#koeriersDienst').html('');

function showText(text) {
    // jquery way of selecting elements by their ID
    let uitzendText = $('#uitzendBureau');
    let koeriersText = $('#koeriersDienst');
    let ymeText = $('#ymeKamminga');

    if (text === 'ymeKamminga') {
        console.log('text ymeKamminga:',text);
        // set the text of the yme element to the desired value
        ymeText.html(text);
    }
    if (text === 'uitzendBureau') {
        console.log('text uitzendBureau', text);
        // set the text of the uitzend element to the desired value
        uitzendText.html(text);
        
        // unset the text of the other elements
        koeriersText.html('');
        ymeText.html('');
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <h1 class="mt-3" onclick="showText('uitzendBureau');">Uitzend<b class="text-orange">bureau</b></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <h1 class="mt-3" onclick="showText('ymeKamminga');">Yme <b class="text-orange">Kamminga</b></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <h1 class="mt-3" onclick="showText('koeriersDienst');">Koeriers<b class="text-orange">dienst</b></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <p class="text-center" id="uitzendBureau">uitzend</p>
    <p class="text-center" id="ymeKamminga">yme</p>
    <p class="text-center" id="koeriersDienst">koerier</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is what I intended it to look like!

Comment: @Mark_Ed as Immortal Dude asked in his answer, is there any specific reason why to not use 1 div and show the text in that element?

Comment: There is not really a reason, but I am pretty new to js and don't know how to do that yet.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let uitzendText = $('#uitzendBureau');
  let koeriersText = $('#koeriersDienst');
  let ymeText = $('#ymeKamminga');

  uitzendText.text('');
  koeriersText.text('');

  // Handle click events
  $(document).on('click', ".heading", function() {
    let el = $(this)
    let elementText = el.data('element-text')

    showText(elementText)
  })
  // Handle showing text
  function showText(text) {

    if (text === 'ymeKamminga') {
      ymeText.text(text);
    }
    if (text === 'uitzendBureau') {
      uitzendText.text(text);
      koeriersText.text('');
      ymeText.text('');
    }

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <h1 class="mt-3 heading" data-element-text="uitzendBureau">Uitzend<b class="text-orange">bureau</b></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <h1 class="mt-3 heading" data-element-text="ymeKamminga">Yme <b class="text-orange">Kamminga</b></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <h1 class="mt-3 heading" data-element-text="koeriersDienst">Koeriers<b class="text-orange">dienst</b></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <p class="text-center" id="uitzendBureau">uitzend</p>
  <p class="text-center" id="ymeKamminga">yme</p>
  <p class="text-center" id="koeriersDienst">koerier</p>
</div>
```

---

**Questions**

1. Wouldn't a simple hide and show of elements work?
2. if you are replacing text then wouldn't one div suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I converted everything to jQuery to keep things simpler

First off, make sure that your code is within the `<head></head>` tags either by importing it through a file or in page code. Doing this makes your code work just fine for me.

Second, make sure you add the value `text` to whatever you put in the `innerHTML` or `.text()`, because adding an empty string to your div will just keep it empty.

```js
uitzendText.innerHTML = $('p#uitzendBureau').text(); // p#uitzendBureau is empty, so you are putting an empty string back into an empty string.
```

Now if you follow my advice and you put this code between the head tags, it will work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#uitzendBureau").text('');
    $("#koeriersDienst").text('');
});
function showText(text) {

    if (text === 'ymeKamminga') {
        console.log(text);
        $('p#ymeKamminga').text(text);
    }
    if (text === 'uitzendBureau') {
        console.log(text);
        $('p#uitzendBureau').text(text);
        $("#koeriersDienst").text('');
        $('p#ymeKamminga').text('');
    }

}
```

as soon as I made sure that the javascript was inside the head tags, your code was working just fine, so all I did was make sure your code also outputs to the DOM what I think your intentions were.

Answer (score 1):

single div version as Immortal Dude suggested:

```js
 function showText(text) {
      $('#text-output').text(text);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
           <h1 class="mt-3" onclick="showText('uitzendBureau');">Uitzend<b class="text-orange">bureau</b></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <h1 class="mt-3" onclick="showText('ymeKamminga');">Yme <b class="text-orange">Kamminga</b></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <h1 class="mt-3" onclick="showText('koeriersDienst');">Koeriers<b class="text-orange">dienst</b></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <p class="text-center" id="text-output"></p>
</div>
```

Since you only display one text at once, using only 1 element to show the showText result might work as well.

Comment: This is an awesome solution, but I think I asked the question wrong, I want the text that is inside the `p` elements to show based on the input given at the`h1` tags. So say I click on `onclick="showText('uitzendBureau');"` I want the text that is inside the `p#uitzendBureau` to show on screen, so in this case `uitzend`.